# Update/multiply a field based on a value in another field

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am new to SQL and have the following issue I would like to solve. The table I would like to edit looks like this:

```
ID | ShopID | ProductID | PurchasePrice
 1 |    1   |    111    | 1,00
 2 |    2   |    111    | 1,40
 3 |    3   |    111    | 1,30
 4 |    1   |    222    | 2,00
 5 |    2   |    222    | 2,50
 6 |    3   |    222    | 2,90
 7 |    1   |    333    | 3,00
 8 |    2   |    333    | 3,80
 9 |    3   |    333    | 3,90
```

- `ID` (unique)
- `ShopID` (3 different values, representing 3 different shops)
- `ProductID` (refers to unique id of different table where more common product info is stored) the same value is available three times for every different `ShopID`
- `PurchasePrice` (over time shops 2 and 3 have edited their pricing, it's a mess now)

The Value of `PurchasePrice` for `ShopID` 2 and 3 should be 10% higher than the `PurchasePrice` for `ShopID` 1 where `ProductID` is the same. How can I easily do this in SQL server 2008?

The table should look like this:

```
ID | ShopID | ProductID | PurchasePrice
 1 |    1   |    111    | 1,00
 2 |    2   |    111    | 1,10
 3 |    3   |    111    | 1,10
 4 |    1   |    222    | 2,00
 5 |    2   |    222    | 2,20
 6 |    3   |    222    | 2,20
 7 |    1   |    333    | 3,00
 8 |    2   |    333    | 3,30
 9 |    3   |    333    | 3,30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE t
SET t.PurchasePrice = p.PurchasePrice*1,10
FROM Table t
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT ProductID,PurchasePrice FROM Table WHERE ShopID=1) p ON t.ProductID = p.ProductID
WHERE t.ShopID<>1
```

Here we get the list of prices in Shop 1  (See the left join query) and update prices of shops other than 1 to shop 1's ProductPrice * 1,10